# Does Ubuntu support my video cards?

Tags: drivers, video, overheating, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 3500 and I have a lot of problem in Linux Mint 12 Lisa. The laptop overheat and shuts down when I have a lot of processing.

I read that the problem is because of the video drivers and the two video cards. The embedded intel can not be desabled.

Can anybody tell me if this problem is solved in Ubuntu?

Thanks,
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

It appears your computer is officially [Ubuntu certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201001-4959/) for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. This means that it has been tested and should work out of the box with Ubuntu. You still may want to boot into a [Ubuntu Live](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) before installing to make sure everything works.